# Query on proper usage of OutputStream

Tags: java, android

Basically attempting to send video data and trying to understand how this whole process works, not sure whether I've put this together properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void OutputStream(BufferedOutputStream out) throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com//");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(mVideoUri)), 8 * 1024);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        assert urlConnection != null;
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is correct, how would I go about calling this method?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't technically using the output stream at all in this case, merely reassigning it several times. The input parameter `out` is being reassigned within the method but never used prior which doesn't seem like what you want to do at all since whatever existing output stream instance reference passed to this method is simply discarded.

You reassign `out` once more and discard the buffered of the socket connection on this line:

```
new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
```

which is mostly harmless in that there isn't any resource leakage (given that `disconnect()` is called) but once again doesn't seem like what you want to do.

Your code also has resource leakage on the last `out` given that it is not closed anywhere within the try-catch-finally block which is a serious flaw. Additionally, the usage of assertions to check for nulls on `out` needs to be promoted to a if-statement to handle the very real possibility that `out` is null in case of a failed URL resolution/open. Assertion tests can be turned off, in which you'd get a NPE (and when turned on, you'll get an `AssertionError`, nether of which is better).

Whilst it's hard to anticipate exactly what your project structure is, the general contract of output stream usage can be seen as follows:

```
public void foo(){
    OutputStream out = null;
    byte[] data = ... // Populated from some data source

    try{
        out = ... // Populated from some source
        out.write(data); // Writes the data to the output destination
    }catch(IOException ex){
        // Handle exception here
    }finally{
        // Only attempt to close the output stream if it was actually opened successfully
        if(out != null){
            try{
                out.close();
            }catch(IOException closeEx){
                // Handle, propogate upwards or log it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output stream is used within the try block such that any exceptions will result in the finally block closing the stream as appropriate, removing the resource leakage. Note the sample `write()` method in the try block, illustrating in the most basic form how OutputStreams can be used to put data into some destination.

Under java 7 (and above), the above example is more compact:

```
public void foo(){
    byte[] data = ... // Populated from some data source

    try(OutputStream out = ...){
        out.write(data); // Writes the data to the output destination
    }catch(IOException ex){
        // Handle exception here
    }
}
```

Utilizing try-with-resources, resource safety can be assured thanks to the `AutoClosable` interface and java 7 (and above's) new syntax. There is one small difference in that exceptions from closing the stream are also bunched into the same catch block instead of being separate as in the first example.